# WCF/SSL error: Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ssl

I've been having a difficult time getting a WCF call in Silverlight to work when using SSL. I've gotten it to a point where WCF tracing says the endpoint is listening but when my code tries to call a function on it WCF Tracing shows the error:

Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.

If I browse to the services URL I properly get the service page, but calling it in code it always fails. Again, this only happens on HTTPS, not before when I was using HTTP. Of course there were a number of config changes to add to use SSL. I should note that the WCF Domain Services functions work fine over SSL, just not the WCF Service. Below are my various config file sections

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <domainServices>
      <endpoints>
        <add name="OData" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </endpoints>
    </domainServices>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000" maxBufferSize="20000">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000" maxStringContentLength="20000" />
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PictureService">
        <endpoint address="https://MyServer/AdvisorDev/PictureService.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="PictureService.IPictureService"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPictureService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://MyServer/AdvisorDev/PictureService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPictureService"
        contract="PictureService.IPictureService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPictureService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Create client:

```
PictureService.PictureServiceClient client = new PictureService.PictureServiceClient();
```

I am running this on my Dev machine using VS 2012 and using IIS as my web server. IIS is using a self-signed certificate. When my site first loads I do get the "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" error, click continue, and the rest of the application runs fine again including the Domain Service calls which use a dynamically created proxy. I create my proxy for this failing WCF service using "Add Service Reference"
One of my sources for SSL is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

This is the service I implemented:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Uploading-and-downloading-images-from-WCF-in-Silverlight.aspx

I appreciate all advice on this, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the service on port 443 (https)? If the service is behind a firewall, that could default the traffic to port 80 (http)

Comment: how does your .config file for the client (silverlight app) look like?

Comment: Knowing it is an old thread, the mentioned error can be resolved by using static WSDL file. For me it was not either inheritance or namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this error was caused by an incorrect namespace in the Service name and contract attributes in the web.config for this service.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having this issue as well, I was receiving the same error. The fix turned out to be removing inheritance from three of my classes.

My WCF service was returning a `List<MyObject>` and three classes inherited from the "MyObject" class. This error was thrown when one of the inheriting classes was included in the list.

Ex:

```
public class MyObject

public class MyObjectTwo : MyObject
```

...

```
List<MyObject> returnList;

MyObjectTwo addingThisBreaksTheService = new MyObjectTwo();

returnList.Add(addingThisBreaksTheService);

return returnList; // Exception thrown after this statement
```